# ruby array reject element and print a message

Tags: arrays, ruby, filtering

I am trying to reject elements from an array and print a message

current code

```rb
users = [
  { name: "Max", age: 32 },
  { name: "Paul", age: 41 },
  { name: "John", age: 30 },
  { name: "", age: 19 },
]

users.reject! do |user|
  next false if user[:name].present?

  custom_logger('user with blank name is not accepted')
  true
end
```

can I change that to a oneliner? to use `||` or `&&` or `and`

```rb
users.reject! do |user|
  user[:name].blank? && custom_logger('user with blank name is not accepted')
end
```

Comment: Your logic seems to make no sense given your input. *No* element in your array has an `:email`, and it's really not clear why checking the presents of `:email` is conflated with reporting users under 19. Also, in your proposed one-liner, `and` is wrong, it doesn't do what you think it does, use `&&` to perform boolean "and".

Comment: You aren't assigning `users.reject` to anything. Why not use `users.each`?

Comment: @user229044 by email I meant name. typo, edited now :)

Comment: @BenStephens this is not the purpose of the question, of course I will assign it to some other variable. I edited it anyway

Comment: You've fundamentally altered your question, rendering existing answers meaningless. Don't do this. If you have a new question with different code, then post a new question.

Comment: I just edited the code so everybody focus on the real question not on typos and useless stuff that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own custom_logger method below, you use yours

Input

```
def custom_logger str
  p str
end

p users.reject { |user| user[:email]&.present? || (user[:age] == 19 && (custom_logger('user with age 19 is not accepted'); true)) }
```

Output

```
"user with age 19 is not accepted"
[{:name=>"Max", :age=>32}, {:name=>"Paul", :age=>41}, {:name=>"John", :age=>30}]
```

I don't know what you have custom_logger method.So I created my method above.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written doesn't work because the line `false if ...` doesn't actually *do* anything. The value of the block is the value of the **last expression**. Just dropping the word `false` somewhere in the middle of the block has no effect; as written your block *always* returns `true` because that line is always the last line evaluated in the block.

If you want to both return true/false *and* perform some action, you should refactor your code as follows, so the last expression in the block (the `if`/`else`) evaluates to `true`/`false`.

```
users.reject do |user|
  if user[:email].present?
    false
  else   
    custom_logger('user with age 19 is not accepted')
    true
  end
end
```

What you should *not* do is cram a bunch of logic onto one line. There is no value in doing this: It's not clearer to read, it's not faster, it's not easier to test, it's not easier to maintain. It's actually *worse* in every way that actually matters.